# MYSQL - Error : #1064

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone I couldn't find the error when inserting values into a table.

It keep showing the error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('1000000001','CASH','PAID','2015-09-05 12:58:51','100000','10000005'),
('10000' at line 2 
"

The coding below is the coding for inserting values into a table call `order`:,

```
INSERT INTO `ORDER` VALUES 
      (`Order_ID`, `Pay_Method`, `Pay_status`, `Order_Time`, `Cus_ID`, `Emp_ID`)
      ('1000000001','CASH','PAID','2015-09-05 12:58:51','100000','10000005'),
      ('1000000002','CASH','PAID','2015-09-05 14:45:00','100001','10000008'),
      ('1000000003','CREDIT CARD','PAID','2015-09-05 16:34:21','100002','10000001'),
      ('1000000004','CASH','PAID','2015-09-05 17:10:10','100003','10000008'), 
      ('1000000005','CREDIT CARD','PAID','2015-09-06 12:33:11','100004','10000006'),
      ('1000000006','CREDIT CARD','PAID','2015-09-06 15:51:15','100006','10000003'),
      ('1000000007','CASH','PAID','2015-09-06 16:20:05','100007','10000002'), 
      ('1000000008','','UNPAID','2015-09-06 17:00:00','100005','10000005'),
      ('1000000009','','UNPAID','2015-09-06 17:23:15','100008','10000001'),
      ('1000000010','','UNPAID','2015-09-06 17:30:34','100009','10000006')
```

and this is the coding for table creation: (Creation success)

```
CREATE TABLE `ORDER` (
      Order_ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
      Pay_Method ENUM ('CASH','CREDIT CARD') NOT NULL,
      Pay_status ENUM ('PAID','UNPAID') NOT NULL,
      Order_Time DATETIME NOT NULL,
      Total_Price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
      Cus_ID CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (Cus_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Cus_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      Emp_ID CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (Emp_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Emp_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

)

I did not insert the values of `Total Price` because I will insert it later on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: values should come after the field list..

Comment: Side note, not ideal to name your table after a reserved word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `ORDER` 
(`Order_ID`, `Pay_Method`, `Pay_status`, `Order_Time`, `Cus_ID`, `Emp_ID`)
VALUES 

      ('1000000001','CASH','PAID','2015-09-05 12:58:51','100000','10000005'),
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The fields come after the table name:

```
INSERT INTO _table_ (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (...)
```